Depending on cell content, draw a TikZ \pic in a PgfplotsTable environment
I would like to draw a TikZ \pic within a 'PgfplotsTable' cell ("Icon") depending on the cell content of another cell ("Component").
To make it easy, the content of the "Component" cell is exactly the label for a predefined TikZ '\pic`.
As you can see in the MWE, this works as far as I put in the "hard coded" \pic label within the TikZ environment.
But why can I not use the value of \pgfplotsretval to print the correct TikZ \pic? As you can see in the output, the values are stored correctly within \pgfplotsretval.
MWE
\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\tikzset{
    pics/dimmer_1/.style={
       code={
                 \draw[red,thick](0,0) rectangle(0.3,-0.3);
            }
    },
     pics/switch_2/.style={
       code={
                 \draw[orange,thick](0,0) rectangle(0.3,-0.3);
            }
    },
}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Component;A;B
dimmer_1;2;3 
switch_2;6;7
switch_3;6;7
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{data.csv}{\csvdata}

\pgfplotstablecreatecol{Icon}{\csvdata}

\pgfplotstableset{
    verb string type,
    columns={Icon,A,B},
    assign column name/.style={/pgfplots/table/column name={\textbf{#1}}},
    every column/.style={
        assign cell content/.code={
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotstablecolname}{Icon}}{
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Component}\of{\csvdata}

                At this point, the component of the current row is:~$\pgfplotsretval$\newline

                \pgfkeysifdefined{/tikz/pics/\pgfplotsretval/.@cmd}{
                    % This works!
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\raisebox{-0.3\height}{\tikz{\pic{dimmer_1};}}}
                    % This doesn't work!
                    % \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\raisebox{-0.3\height}{\tikz{\pic{\pgfplotsretval};}}}
                }{
                    The component:~$\pgfplotsretval$ is not defined!
                }
            }{}
        },
    },
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\csvdata}\\
\end{document}

OUTPUT


note that nesting tikzpictures isn't supported and is expected to fail. didn't investigate whether that's relevant here, but I'm guessing pgfplotstable is using pgfpicture or tikzpicture or something under the hood. though I assume the issue with the commented line is simply expansion. the parser doesn't see the stuff it needs to see. you'd need to expand the return value before pgf/tikz sees it.

one safer and more efficient way to do this would be to save the symbols in boxes and then use the boxes. this will run more efficiently if you use the same pic multiple times (which you presumably do) as using a box is much faster than rendering pgf/tikz code. but it is also safe to then use inside or outside the tikzpicture environment.

@cfr Thanks for your comments! I will try to investigate the given answer :)

As @cfr noted in the comments, it is an expansion issue. The solution is along the lines of @egreg's answer to a similar question.
Make sure that \pgfplotsretval is expanded before the rest of the line, by replacing the line
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\raisebox{-0.3\height}{\tikz{\pic{\pgfplotsretval};}}}

by
\expanded{\noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\noexpand\raisebox{-0.3\noexpand\height}{\noexpand\tikz{\noexpand\pic{\pgfplotsretval};}}}}

The other issue raised by @cfr is that, first, nesting tikz/pgf may cause problems, and second, retypsetting the tikz code with every line of the csv file may take a long time if the csv file is long. To solve this issue, you can either save just the result of \tikz\pic in a box:
\newcommand\savepic[1]{%
  \expandafter\newsavebox\csname pics/#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\savebox\csname pics/#1\endcsname{\tikz\pic{#1};}%
}
\newcommand\usepic[1]{%
  \expandafter\usebox\csname pics/#1\endcsname
}
\savepic{dimmer_1}% Save \pic{dimmer_1} in a box called \pic/dimmer_1
\savepic{switch_2}% Save \pic{switch_2} in a box called \pic/switch_2
\begin{document}
...
\expanded{\noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\noexpand\raisebox{-0.3\noexpand\height}{\noexpand\usepic{\pgfplotsretval}}}}

or the entire cell content including \raisebox:
\newcommand\savepic[1]{%
  \expandafter\newsavebox\csname pics/#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\savebox\csname pics/#1\endcsname{\raisebox{-0.3\height}{\tikz\pic{#1};}}%
}
\newcommand\usepic[1]{%
  \expandafter\usebox\csname pics/#1\endcsname
}
\savepic{dimmer_1}% Save \pic{dimmer_1} in a box called \pic/dimmer_1
\savepic{switch_2}% Save \pic{switch_2} in a box called \pic/switch_2
\begin{document}
...
\expanded{\noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\noexpand\usepic{\pgfplotsretval}}}


\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\tikzset{
    pics/dimmer_1/.style={
       code={
                 \draw[red,thick](0,0) rectangle(0.3,-0.3);
            }
    },
     pics/switch_2/.style={
       code={
                 \draw[orange,thick](0,0) rectangle(0.3,-0.3);
            }
    },
}

% \newcommand\savepic[1]{%
%   \expandafter\newsavebox\csname pics/#1\endcsname
%   \expandafter\savebox\csname pics/#1\endcsname{\tikz\pic{#1};}%
% }
\newcommand\savepic[1]{%
  \expandafter\newsavebox\csname pics/#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\savebox\csname pics/#1\endcsname{\raisebox{-0.3\height}{\tikz\pic{#1};}}%
}
\newcommand\usepic[1]{%
  \expandafter\usebox\csname pics/#1\endcsname
}

\savepic{dimmer_1}
\savepic{switch_2}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Component;A;B
dimmer_1;2;3 
switch_2;6;7
switch_3;6;7
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{data.csv}{\csvdata}

\pgfplotstablecreatecol{Icon}{\csvdata}

\pgfplotstableset{
    verb string type,
    columns={Icon,A,B},
    assign column name/.style={/pgfplots/table/column name={\textbf{#1}}},
    every column/.style={
        assign cell content/.code={
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotstablecolname}{Icon}}{
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Component}\of{\csvdata}

                At this point, the component of the current row is:~$\pgfplotsretval$\newline

                \pgfkeysifdefined{/tikz/pics/\pgfplotsretval/.@cmd}{
%                    \expanded{\noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\noexpand\raisebox{-0.3\noexpand\height}{\noexpand\tikz{\noexpand\pic{\pgfplotsretval};}}}}
%                    \expanded{\noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\noexpand\raisebox{-0.3\noexpand\height}{\noexpand\usepic{\pgfplotsretval}}}}
                    \expanded{\noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\noexpand\usepic{\pgfplotsretval}}}
                }{
                    The component:~$\pgfplotsretval$ is not defined!
                }
            }{}
        },
    },
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\csvdata}\\
\end{document}


Amazing! I'm just struggling with some settings in my real environment but first of all thank you, the MWE is working fine!
